# How to iterate over a List of numbers and check if there are pairs of numbers that add up to a given value using Scala?

Tags: scala

I have to generate a list of prime numbers smaller than a given number and then find all pairs of the generated prime numbers that add up to that value.

E.g.
num = 12

smaller_primes = List(3, 5, 7, 11)

Desirable outcome: List((5, 7))

I had no problem with generating the list of smaller prime numbers, but I don't know how to check what pairs fulfill the requirement. This is what I tried:

```
def check_sum(n: Int) = 
    val get_primes = (List.range(2, n)).filter(num => check_prime_bool(num))  // generating list of smaller prime numbers
    val x = for {
        a <- get_primes
        b <- get_primes
        if a + b == n 
    } yield (a,b)
    x
```

This solution works but I can't use the for/yield construction, I can only use functions like map(), filter(), etc.

Comment: One line solution: `def check_sum(n: Int) = (2 to n/2).flatten(i => if(check_prime_bool(i) && check_prime_bool(n-i)) Some((i, n-i)) else None)`

Comment: Thanks, that's a really neat solution! However, I can't wrap my head around why `.flatten()` alone gets the job done. I tried using `flatMap()` as well as  `map(...).flatten()` , which both yielded the same correct result. Is there something I'm missing about the `.flatten()` method implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **exact** same implementation you have already implemented, but using map, ... would be:

```scala
def checkSum(n: Int) = {
  val getPrimes = ((2 to n).filter(check_prime_bool)
  getPrimes.flatMap { a => 
    getPrimes.map(b => (a, b)).filter(b => a + b == n)
  }
}
```

Take it like this, the first reverse arrow in the for comprehension is compiled into: `getPrimes.flatMap { a => }` (You're naming the variable for iteration as "a" inside your for comprehension). The second line of the for comprehension is compiled into: `getPrimes.map { b => }` (note the variable "b" name, it's just the same as you're passing). "if" is compiled into `.withFilter` method, you can use `filter` instead.

But if you wanted to, I can suggest another implementations which is tailrec and is O(n) instead of O(n^2) (It doesn't use map, flatMap, ..., if anyone can suggest a better implementation for this approach, you're welcome to edit this answer):

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec

// assuming primes are sorted (since (2 to n).filter(isPrime) which you're using in this case, is sorted)
@tailrec
def checkSum(primes: Array[Int], acc: List[(Int, Int)] = List.empty, leftIndex: Int = 0, rightIndex: Int, num: Int): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  if (leftIndex >= rightIndex) acc // pointers have reached each other, that's the end of the list
  else {
    val left = primes(leftIndex)
    val right = primes(rightIndex)
    val sum = left + right
    if (sum == num) checkSum(primes, (left -> right) +: acc, leftIndex + 1, rightIndex - 1, num)
    else if (sum < num) { // move left pointer to right
      checkSum(primes, acc, leftIndex + 1, rightIndex, num)
    } else { // move right pointer to left
      checkSum(primes, acc, leftIndex, rightIndex - 1, num)
    }
  }
}

val primeNumbers = (2 to 12).filter(isPrime).toArray
checkSum(primeNumbers, rightIndex = primeNumbers.length - 1, num = 12) 
// => List[(5, 7)]
```

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JPbs2mbOS5WrqBX0shiZpQ

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Regarding your tailrec solution, I think we could change this line: `if (sum == num) checkSum(primes, (left -> right) +: acc, leftIndex + 1, rightIndex + 1, num)` to `if (sum == num) checkSum(primes, (left -> right) :: acc, leftIndex + 1, rightIndex + 1, num)` if we really cared about the performance (`+:` is O(n) operation on a List, when `::` is O(1)).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your tailrec solution would work for all numbers

Comment: @HumbleIdiot Actually +: is for prepending, It's O(1). If you look at the implementation, `+:` uses exactly `::` under the hood. It's just an alias for `prepended`. What you're saying is for `:+`. But yes, :: also works just the same. And about the second sentence, it works, try it out in the scastie link I provided in the first comment.

Comment: oh yes, you're right, my bad. I mistook `+:`  for `:+`  :)

Comment: But still, when I try out your code you provided in the first comment on data like `val primes = List(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)` and `num = 22`, I get an error.

Comment: @HumbleIdiot, that was a typo in scastie :) the code in the answer is fine. The mistake was when two pointers add up to the number, instead of making them each 1 step closer, i moved them both to right, 19+3=22, moving the right ptr to right causes error.